# Taskbar icons won't change

Tags: windows-7, taskbar

I have been trying to change the icons for the shortcuts on my taskbar on Win7, but they don't seem be changing except for one of them.

I have done this before in the past, and it worked, but suddenly it doesn't appear, even when I kill the explorer.exe process and restart it, restart win7. Nothing seems to work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What have you been trying?

Comment: Are you referring to pinning or quick launch?

Comment: Sorry If I haven't been clear.

I right click on the icon for the program on the taskbar, it shows the jumplist (If availabel) then right click again, choose properties, than choose change icon. I choose an icon, but that new icon doesn't appear, the old one stays.
Restarting Win7 doesn't do a thing.

Comment: Never mind. It suddenly worked.


I clicked on the programs to start and all icons changed. It didn't happen before then. A Win7 quirk probably.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open Explorer to the following location:

```
%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar
```

Then change the icons by right clicking and going to change icon and locating the .ico file of your icon you'd like to use.

Once you change all of your icons you want to change, open up task manager (Control+Alt+Delete) and end explorer.exe
Then click File > New Task (Run..)
Type Explorer.exe and press Enter.
It will work then...enjoy!

PS, I only know this because I just figured out how to do this myself and successfully changed all of my icons just a few minutes ago!

Comment: Thank you for your answer (especially for the path)! I think the most important point is to restart the **"Windows Explorer" process** in the task manager because it caches the icons in the task bar. Restarting it forces re-loading all icons.

Comment: On Windows 10 this is not working for me. Ended up needing to delete the IconCache as in the PeterDanis answer

Answer (score 3):

On Windows 7 (and probably on other versions too) follow these steps:

- go to `%userprofile%\AppData\Local`
- delete `IconCache.db` file
- in Task manager kill `explorer.exe` process
- in Task manager start a new `explorer.exe` process (through `File > New task (Run)`)

Comment: Thank you! Your directions are the only solution for me.

Comment: This answer works for Win10 ... the currently selected correct answer is not working

Answer (score 0):

If the [other solution](https://superuser.com/a/271881/494) does not work, try [the following](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/28847/how-to-customize-your-windows-7-taskbar-icons-for-any-app/):

1. Go to: `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar`
2. Copy the shortcut to another location
3. Change the icon (of the copy), by right-clicking on the shortcut and selecting Properties > Shortcut > Change Icon...
4. Unpin the existing shortcut from the taskbar
5. Drag the new shortcut to the taskbar